# Poisson Distribution VB.NET and PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, statistics, distribution, poisson

Dear can anyone explain why in PHP the code for this Poisson Distribution
execute correctly an the same code in VB.NET is wrong?
thanks

PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; 10 ; $i++) {   
     $Poisson =  $Poisson + (((pow(($TassodiDomanda*$LT),$i))/factorial($i))*exp(-$TassodiDomanda* $LT));     
    if ($Poisson > 0.9) {
    $Result = $i ;
    return $Result;
    break;
    }
    }
```

VB.NET:

```
 For i = 1 To 100
        Poisson += (((((Math.Pow((tassodidomanda * LT), i)) / Factorial(i))) * Math.Exp(-(tassodidomanda * LT)))
        If Poisson >= 0.9 Then
            richiesti = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: try replacing `Exit For` with `return richiesti`

Comment: Well, it would help if you would say more about exactly what the difference or error is.

Comment: you're right I deleted that line, but wasn`t this the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good news,
I solved it by using this fantastic library

[http://accord-framework.net/](http://http://accord-framework.net/accord-framework.net/)

for more detailed informations

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/accord-net

Thanks to these developers